# "AttributeError: normalize" Error when running Roboflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, image-classification, fast-ai, roboflow

**When running the code for the Roboflow image classification in jupyter notebook, my team and I keep getting the same error.**

**If someone could please help us get a better understanding of what this error means and why we keep getting it that would be very much appreciated!!**

**This is the code:**

`data = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path, size=220, num_workers=4).normalize(imagenet_stats)`

**And this is the error:**

````
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mf/sm4q6hh96j5bq3f327w8px0m0000gn/T/ipykernel_42187/1206335196.py in <module>
----> 1 data = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path, size=220, num_workers=4).normalize(imagenet_stats)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastcore/basics.py in __getattr__(self, k)
    387         if self._component_attr_filter(k):
    388             attr = getattr(self,self._default,None)
--> 389             if attr is not None: return getattr(attr,k)
    390         raise AttributeError(k)
    391     def __dir__(self): return custom_dir(self,self._dir())

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastcore/basics.py in __getattr__(self, k)
    387         if self._component_attr_filter(k):
    388             attr = getattr(self,self._default,None)
--> 389             if attr is not None: return getattr(attr,k)
    390         raise AttributeError(k)
    391     def __dir__(self): return custom_dir(self,self._dir())

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/data/core.py in __getattr__(self, k)
    333         return res if is_indexer(it) else list(zip(*res))
    334 
--> 335     def __getattr__(self,k): return gather_attrs(self, k, 'tls')
    336     def __dir__(self): return super().__dir__() + gather_attr_names(self, 'tls')
    337     def __len__(self): return len(self.tls[0])

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastcore/transform.py in gather_attrs(o, k, nm)
    163     att = getattr(o,nm)
    164     res = [t for t in att.attrgot(k) if t is not None]
--> 165     if not res: raise AttributeError(k)
    166     return res[0] if len(res)==1 else L(res)
    167 

AttributeError: normalize```
````

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Roboflow error response, its a Python error response which occurs when an attribute reference or assignment fails.

Example: Assigning `x=10` then attempting `x.append()` will throw an AttributeError because the variable is an integer type it does not support the append method.

I would start by taking a look at the datatype you are attempting to normalize and see if `.normalize()` is supported for that datatype